# Parameterized test using fixture with yield. Fixture doesn't run cleanup code after yield

Tags: python, testing, pytest, fixtures

I have a fixture that inserts the data in DB and removes it after `yield`

```py
@pytest.fixture
def add_marketplace_ts(session: Session):
    marketplace = Marketplace(
        name="themeselection",
        support_duration=148,
        purchase_verification_url="https://google.com",
    )

    session.add(marketplace)
    session.commit()
    session.refresh(marketplace)
    yield marketplace
    session.delete(marketplace)
    session.commit()
```

I have a test which uses this function but that test is parameterized:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "endpoint",
    [
        "/github/access-form",
        "/github/issue-form",
    ],
)
def test_marketplace_return(
    client: TestClient, session: Session, endpoint: str, add_marketplace_ts: Marketplace
):

    r = client.get(endpoint)

    assert r.status_code == 200

    data = r.json()

    assert data["marketplaces"] == IsList(
        IsPartialDict(
            id=1,
            name="themeselection",
            purchase_verification_url="https://google.com",
        )
    )
    assert data["brands"] == []
    assert data["product_w_technology_name"] == []
```

When I run the above test it calls the fixture twice but it doesn't run code written after `yield` once the first execution is complete. This results in the same record being inserted twice and raises error *(DB unique error)*.

How can I let pytest run the code after `yield` in fixture on each execution regardless of the number of parameters provided by the test function?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this was my mistake.

This is because when you insert the data in DB its id is autoincremented and the second time when data is inserted its id is 2 which makes test fail even if the first row is deleted.